# R ifelse() evaluates a condition and returns match

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe

```
countryname <- c("Viet Nam", "Viet Nam", "Viet Nam", "Viet Nam", "Viet Nam")
year <- c(1974, 1975, 1976, 1977,1978)

df <- data.frame(countryname, year)
```

that is in a long country by year format.

I would like to create a function that can standardize countrynames conditional upon the year of the observation. I created a function that is able to pull from a data frame `cnames` and standardize names but this is only useful for cross-sections and if country names do not vary over time.

```
country <- c("Vietnam, North", "Vietnam, N.", "Vietnam North", "Viet Nam", "Democratic Republic Of Vietnam")
standardize <- c("Vietnam, Democratic Republic of", "Vietnam, Democratic Republic of", "Vietnam, Democratic Republic of", "Vietnam, Democratic Republic of", "Vietnam, Democratic Republic of")
panel <- c("Vietnam", "Vietnam","Vietnam","Vietnam","Vietnam")
time <- c(1976,1976,1976,1976,1976)

cnames <- data.frame(country, standardize, panel, time)
```

The function to standardize is

```
country_name <- function(x) {
   return(cnames[match(x,cnames$country),]$standardize)
}
```

However, as you can see this doesn't account for any variation of country names over time. I've tried a number of different things and the closest I've come is this function.

```
country_panel <- function(x, y) {

  ifelse(cnames$time < y, 
    return(cnames[match(x, cnames$country),]$panel),
    return(cnames[match(x, cnames$country),]$standardize)
  )
}
```

I use a `dplyr` chain to pull in the data frame and then use `mutate` to create a new variable that ideally that captures the difference in names for countries.

```
d1 <- df %>%
    mutate(new_name = country_panel(countryname, year))
```

The problem that I'm finding is that the function only evaluates `y` in the `country_panel` function as a single object not as a vector. If I input an integer that is greater or less than `cnames$time` it evaluates correctly but passes the value for every row.

How can I have this function evaluate each `cnames$country` and `cnames$time` relationship to `df$year` and return the correct `cnames$panel` or `cnames$standardize`?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your `country_panel` function calls `panel()` but that function's code is not included here.

Comment: Thanks, that was supposed to be return()

Comment: Take out `return`, it is stopping your function from continuing. (See answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d1
#   countryname year                        new_name
# 1    Viet Nam 1974 Vietnam, Democratic Republic of
# 2    Viet Nam 1975 Vietnam, Democratic Republic of
# 3    Viet Nam 1976 Vietnam, Democratic Republic of
# 4    Viet Nam 1977                         Vietnam
# 5    Viet Nam 1978                         Vietnam
```

All you need to do is make sure your data frames are set to `stringsAsFactors=F` when you define them, i.e. (`df <- data.frame(countryname, year, stringsAsFactors=F)`). And take out the `return` command:

```
country_panel <- function(x, y) {
  ifelse(cnames$time < y, 
    cnames[match(x, cnames$country),]$panel,
    cnames[match(x, cnames$country),]$standardize
  )
}
```

The reasoning behind it is that `return` stops the function in its tracks once it's called. So your data frame is being populated by a single value output. That's why they were all the same.

Comment: This worked on the replication code but still doesn't work when I pull in an actual csv using readr's `read_csv` which is supposed to default `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` correct?

Comment: When you run `str(df)` does it say `factor` for any of the columns?

Comment: No, they are either integer or character. 

I also just ran with the real data using `read.csv` and set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and it is not working,

Comment: Saying `it doesn't work` helps very little. Also, what else would you like me to do without your data when the example you provided has been solved?

Comment: My apologies. It was just returning the `cnames[match(x, cnames$country),]$panel for everything.

I pushed everything onto GitHub [here](https://github.com/dsself/StandardCountries/blob/master/paneldev/panel_test.R) if you want to see it with the real data

Answer (score 0):

You could join the tables based on year and country name:

```
left_join(df, cnames, by = c("countryname" = "country", "year" = "time"))

  countryname year                     standardize   panel
1    Viet Nam 1974                            <NA>    <NA>
2    Viet Nam 1975                            <NA>    <NA>
3    Viet Nam 1976 Vietnam, Democratic Republic of Vietnam
4    Viet Nam 1977                            <NA>    <NA>
5    Viet Nam 1978                            <NA>    <NA>
```

Comment: I looked into the join option and is something I want to avoid. The whole purpose for this function is to reduce the error that arises from joining a number of different data sets that each have significant variations in country names.

Comment: I should also say that I'm looking to add onto a package I developed [here](https://github.com/dsself/StandardCountries) that handles panel data.