# read_csv from R readr treats data differently than generated data

Tags: r, dplyr

I had an issue using ifelse() in a function which was initially solved in this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325531/r-ifelse-evaluates-a-condition-and-returns-match). After implementing the suggestions the code performed exactly as desired. The code is below

```
country_panel <- function(x, y) {
  ifelse(cnames$time < y, 
    cnames[match(x, cnames$country),]$panel,
    cnames[match(x, cnames$country),]$standardize
 )
 }
```

Generate the fake data with this

```
 countryname <- c("Viet Nam", "Viet Nam", "Viet Nam", "Viet Nam", "Viet Nam")
year <- c(1974, 1975, 1976, 1977,1978)

df <- data.frame(countryname, year, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

country <- c("Vietnam, North", "Vietnam, N.", "Vietnam North", "Viet Nam",   "Democratic Republic Of Vietnam")
standardize <- c("Vietnam, Democratic Republic of", "Vietnam, Democratic Republic of", "Vietnam, Democratic Republic of", "Vietnam, Democratic Republic of", "Vietnam, Democratic Republic of")
panel <- c("Vietnam", "Vietnam","Vietnam","Vietnam","Vietnam")
time <- c(1976,1976,1976,1976,1976)

cnames <- data.frame(country, standardize, panel, time, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Evaluate using the function using

```
 d1 <- df %>% 
   mutate(new_name = country_panel(countryname, year))
```

However, when I went to implement the suggestions with the real data the problem returned where the function does not evaluate the condition in the `ifelse` statement and only returns the `$panel` value.

Because using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame` worked with the fake data I thought that using `read.csv(PATH, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` would work instead of using `read_csv` but they both perform equally.

I should also note that I checked the attributes of each vector in the data frame using `str()` and forced them to match what I found in the fake data.

The real data and scripts to replicate everything can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/dsself/StandardCountries/tree/master/paneldev)

Here is `dput(head(cnames))`

```
structure(list(country = c("AFGHANISTAN", "Afghanistan", "albania", 
"ALBANIA", "Albania", "ALGERIA"), standardize = c("Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Algeria"), time = c(2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), panel = c("Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Algeria")), .Names =      c("country", 
"standardize", "time", "panel"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

and `dput(head(d1))`

```
structure(list(countryname = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan"), 
     year = 1970:1975), .Names = c("countryname", "year"), class =    c("tbl_df", 
 "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(new_name = country_panel(countryname, year))
df2 <- structure(list(country = c("AFGHANISTAN", "Afghanistan", "albania",
  "ALBANIA", "Albania", "ALGERIA"), standardize = c("Afghanistan", 
  "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Algeria"), time = c(2015L, 
  2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), panel = c("Afghanistan", 
  "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Algeria")), .Names =      c("country", 
  "standardize", "time", "panel"), class = c("tbl_df", "data.frame"
  ), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

d2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(new_name = country_panel(countryname, year))
```

This gives:

```
Error: wrong result size (5), expected 6 or 1
```

The immediate problem is that `mutate` expects `country_panel` to return 6 values since `df2` has 6 rows (`dim(df2)`), or, alternatively, 1 value that it would recycle as needed. Your first example with made up data in fact only works because the number of rows happen to match.

Try running your example again after running:

```
debug(country_panel)
...
# after done:
undebug(country_panel)
```

This will give you a line by line view of the function as it is called, and you can check out all the objects that exist or are created within the function as it runs (exit anytime with q).

Instead of using `ifelse` it might be better to use sequential matching, first for country and then time. Or you could try just making a data frame out of the x and y vectors passed to the function, merging with cnames, and then picking the name you want from conditions within the data frame.

Comment: It does look like the `ifelse` is the wrong path because I didn't understand how it would perform.

I don't really understand what you mean by sequential matching. 

Can you explain why setting a condition in `cnames[match(x, cnames$country),]$panel` doesn't work? Is it because it subsets?

For example

`cnames[match(x, cnames$country) & cnames$time < y,]$panel`

Comment: It's a bit weird code. For example, `match` only returns the first match, so if you have repeated `country` in `cnames` with I guess different years, is that ok? It's vectorized code, which in the long term is probably good, but right now I would aim for getting the basics right. I would first aim for a function and `cnames` data structure that for 1 country name in 1 year, gives you the standardized name/code/whatever you want. Once the function does that, then it might be worth optimizing/vectorizing, but it may not turn out to be that necessary at all.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused how you use `time` in this. I know for panel data you need it because of occasional mergers/splits, but is it an issue for names as well? If so, would it make more sense to specific start and end dates for use of a particular name, rather than repeated name-year records?

Comment: Yeah, so I want to address cases like North/South Vietnam or Yemen and I want to avoid expanding my set of country variations to have a unique instance for each year 1900-2014. Instead, I has hoping to just have it check `$time` and if it was > than that return a different vector.

I've instead just done 1 off cases using nested `ifelse()`